# swiftui button does not show up when value does not exist when doing a filter list

Tags: ios, database, firebase, filter, swiftui

[When user has a userid ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSnYQ.png)Question:
I'm trying to have my "Add your profile name" Button to show up if the user has yet to add a username into the firebase database.

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hEjw.png)
Currently, the button to update the user's username does show up since their userID exists in the firebase.

But, for new users, since they have yet to add a username into the firebase database, the filtering list of course skips over all the data since $0.userID.contains(String(describing: uidx)is not valid. I have tried adding || model.listTwo.count > 0 to the filtering list and do a ( book.userID != (String(describing: uidx) but when I do that, the user has a userID also gets the add your profile button if there are more than two users in the database.

How can I make sure the "Add your profile name" Button only shows up if the userID of the current user does not show up in the firebase database?

```
struct Settings: View {
let exampleColor : Color = Color(red: 150/255, green: 185/255, blue: 208/255)
@AppStorage("log_Status") var log_Status = true
@State var userID = ""
@State var userName = ""
@State var exists = false
@ObservedObject var model = ListViewModel()
var temp = false
let uidx = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var body: some View {

 if log_Status{
        ZStack{
            Image("Wallpaper10").resizable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
                Section{
                    Form{
                        Group{
                            Text("Your current profile name: " )
                            List( model.listTwo.filter({  $0.userID.contains(String(describing: uidx)) || model.listTwo.count > 0 })) {
                                    book in
                                    if (book.exists == true) && ( book.userID == (String(describing: uidx)) ){
                                        Text(book.userName).font(.headline).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center).font(Font.headline.weight(.semibold))
                                        TextField("Update your user name", text: $userName).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                        Button(action: {
                                            model.updateClub(userID:  String(describing: uidx), userName: userName)
                                            
                                        }, label: {
                                            Text("Submit change").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center).font(Font.headline.weight(.semibold))
                                        })
                                    }
                                    else if ( !book.userID.contains("") ) {
                                        TextField("Add your profile name", text: $userName).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                        
                                        Button(action: {
                                            model.addProfileData(userID:  String(describing: uidx), userName: userName, exists: true)
                                            userID = ""
                                            userName = ""
                                            exists = true
                                            
                                        }, label: {
                                            Text("Submit change").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center).font(Font.headline.weight(.semibold))
                                        })
                                    } } }
                    }}
                Button("Logout")
                {
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signOut()
                    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                    withAnimation{
                        log_Status = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    init(){
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    model.getDataTwo()
   }
```

}

```
struct ProfileInfo: Identifiable, Codable {
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var userID: String
var userName: String
var exists: Bool
```

}

final class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var list = Clubs

```
@Published var listTwo = [ProfileInfo]()
    func updateClub(userID: String, userName: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("profileInfo").whereField("userID",isEqualTo: userID).getDocuments{
        (snap, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        for i in snap!.documents {
            var userName2 = i.get("userName") as! String
            userName2 = userName
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                i.reference.updateData(["userName": userName2])
            }
        }
    }
    
}




func addProfileData(userID: String, userName: String, exists: Bool){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("profileInfo").addDocument(data: ["userID": userID, "userName": userName, "exists": exists]){
        error in
        if error == nil {
            
        }
        else{
            self.getDataTwo()
            
        }
    }
}

    func getDataTwo() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    //let x = ""
    db.collection("profileInfo").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if error == nil {
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    
                    self.listTwo = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                        return ProfileInfo(id: d.documentID,
                                           userID: d["userID"] as? String ?? "",
                                           userName: d["userName"] as? String ?? "",
                                           exists: d["exists"] as? Bool ?? true
                        )
                    }}
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    }}

  NavigationLink(destination: Settings()) { Image("settings").resizable().frame(width: 55, height: 55, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
```

Update

```
struct ProfileInfo: Identifiable, Codable {
var id: String
var userName: String
var exists: Bool


 }


    func getDataTwo() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("profileInfo").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if error == nil {
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    
                    self.listTwo = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                        return ProfileInfo(id: d["id"] as? String ?? "",
                                           userName: d["userName"] as? String ?? "",
                                           exists: d["exists"] as? Bool ?? true
                        )
                    }}
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    }}

   func addProfileData(id: String, userName: String, exists: Bool){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("profileInfo").addDocument(data: ["id": id, "userName": userName, "exists": exists]){
        error in
        if error == nil {
            
        }
        else{
            self.getDataTwo()
        }}}
```

Comment: Can you share the user model? Is the userID property is optional? And you just want to filter out all the ids that are not nil?

Comment: @MrDeveloper Unfortunately that does not answer my question :c

Comment: @CloudBalancing I updated the code i provided up in my question. I also provided a picture of what the screen currently looks like. The "Add your profile name" shows up currently even though the user does have a username. If i change the if statements in the code and what is filtered in the list to remove the add your profile name from users who do have a userid saved in the firebase, then the 'add your profile name' vanishes as well for users that do not have a userid saved in the database

Comment: @CloudBalancing what i want is how to show the "Add your profile name" button to show up within the {} of the list if only the user's userid does not exist yet in the database

Comment: You use the same uidx var for all elements in the list ?

Comment: @PtitXav uidx is the current's user's id, and each username has a distinct uidx

Comment: Did you check what you have in String(describing: uidx) ? It may not be what you think as uidx is an optional string not a string

Comment: May I suggest something? I think a different approach will improve the code and greatly simplify what you're doing. First, in your `ProfileInfo` collection, create each users document using the users uid as the documentId. That will eliminate the need to also store the uid within the document AND will eliminate the query. Then when the user authenticates, attempt to read that document using getDocument using the usersUid as documentId. If no data is contained in the snapshot, show the button (because it doesn't exist)

Comment: @Jay I added an updated version of couple of the functions and the profileInfo struct. I am going to be saving id with the information i usually save as the userID. Not sure if this is the direction you are telling me, and also how will. I be able to show the button in the Settings View if the id does not exist? Is that handled in the settings view?

Comment: @Jay Also, I don't need to make a list?

Comment: No you do not need to make a list. If you want to show a "Add your profile" button you need to determine if it should be shown or not. As per my comment above, when the user authenticates, attempt to read their profile document; if it doesn't exist, show the button in the UI, if it does exists, no need to show the button. Performing queries, filtering etc has a LOT more overhead than just reading a document which is why I suggested a better structure for that task.

Answer (score -2):

I just decided to filter out the list and if the count is zero then to just show the 'add your profile name' button, otherwise it will just filter the list out to do the rest with editing the profile : )